# Get visible items when Controller first appear?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

This's what i did:

```
public func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    // Current visible items
    let items =  messagesCollectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems
    
    // Changed items
    let itemsSet = Set.init(items)
    let unionSet = itemsSet.union(self.visibleItems)
    let intersectSet = itemsSet.intersection(self.visibleItems)
    unionSet.subtracting(intersectSet)
}
```

But `indexPathsForVisibleItems`  is not accurate when page first appear, and if collectionView scrolls that works fine again...

Any advises?

Comment: why not just add this inside `viewDidAppear()` in  your viewController?

Comment: If do that in `didAppear`, the visibleCells number UILabel will appear obviously, not smoothly enough~`

Answer (score 0):

Your code inside the body of `func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView)` will only be executed when scrolling on collection view so obviously when view appears there is no scroll event and the code won't be executed.

You need a place that will trigger your code when view appears, I would suggest `viewDidAppear(_:)`

Another approach would be to observe the `contentSize` property on the collection view.

```swift
self.yourCollectionView?.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "contentSize", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.Old, context: nil)
```

and handle the update in `observeValue(forKeyPath:of:change:context:)` delegate method.